# Why do we get an error? Error sending email: The SMTP server required a secure connection, or the client was not authenticated

Tags: powershell

```
try {
    $credentials = new-object Management.Automation.PSCredential “ad@foc.ru”, (“dasfkjaehj5” | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force) 
    $mailParams  = @{
            'To'          = "prices@mits.ru"
            'From'        = "ad@foc.ru"
            'Encoding'    = 'UTF8'
            'Subject'     = "340."
            'Body'        = "Сообщение отправлено автоматически"
            'Smtpserver'  = "mail.foc.ru"
            'Port'        = 25
            'Attachments' = "E:\FTP\EMEX\price_forceauto.csv"
            'Credential'  = $credentials 
    
    }
  
    Send-MailMessage @mailParams -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
    $errorMessage = "Error sending email: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    Write-Warning $errorMessage
    Add-Content -Path 'E:\FTP\EMEX\error.txt' -Value $errorMessage
}
```

We recieve an error:

```
Error sending email: The SMTP server required a secure connection, or the client was not authenticated. Server Response: 5.7.1 Local mailbox price@avto-olimp.com not found.**
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - try changing `Port` value to `587` or `465` and add `UseSsl = $true` to `$mailParams`

Comment: we recieved new error Error sending email: Unable to read data from transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

Comment: after eding changes  UseSsl = $true and change port number 587 and 465

Comment: Well, then you need to ask the operators of `"mail.foc.ru"` what port to talk SMTP over TLS on :)

Answer (score 1):

FYI...

SSL sites, now require you to also do this in your code.

```
# Required for use with web SSL sites
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Comment: i mean in program above

Comment: To stay simple, just put it at the very top of your scripts.